# Selenium Web Driver : Handle Confirm Box using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am using the following code for handling the alert box after clicking an action but it isn't working
Can somebody please help.

This is where I call the handler. clickOnAlert() after clickOnAddQuote() is called alert box appears.

```
System.out.println("before add to quote");
this.clickOnAddQuote();
System.out.println("before alert");
this.clickOnAlert();
System.out.println("after alert");
```

function clickOnAlert()

```
public void clickOnAlert() {
        System.out.println("In click");
        Alert alert = webdriverSession().switchTo().alert();
        System.out.println("after constructor");
        alert.accept();
    }
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the exception that you are seeing?

Comment: @niharika_neo It is showing org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: No alert is present (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) .  BUt when I do it manually it shows a confirm box

Comment: can you share some pulic url where the issue can be seen?  Also, via automation, does the window pop-up?

Comment: The `Alert` class will only work if standard javascript alerts. (Those that you get when you execute something like `alert(test)`. If it is not a standard JS alert, this will not work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

different dialogs handling using selenium webDriver:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class JavaScriptAlertTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver myTestDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    myTestDriver.get("...blablabla....");

    myTestDriver.manage().window().maximize();

    myTestDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'alert']")).click();

    Alert javascriptAlert = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(javascriptAlert.getText()); // Get text on alert box
    javascriptAlert.accept();

    System.out.println("*************prompt******************************************");

    myTestDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'prompt']")).click();

    Alert javascriptprompt = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();
    javascriptprompt.sendKeys("This is Selenium Training");

    System.out.println(javascriptprompt.getText()); // Get text on alert box

    javascriptprompt.accept();
    javascriptprompt = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();

    System.out.println(javascriptprompt.getText()); // Get text on alert box
    javascriptprompt.accept();

    myTestDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'prompt']")).click();

    javascriptprompt = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();

    System.out.println(javascriptprompt.getText()); // Get text on alert box

    javascriptprompt.dismiss();
    javascriptprompt = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();

    System.out.println(javascriptprompt.getText()); // Get text on alert box
    javascriptprompt.accept();

    System.out.println("***********************************confirm dialog box****************************");
    myTestDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'confirm']")).click();

    Alert javascriptconfirm = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();
    javascriptconfirm.accept();

    javascriptconfirm = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(javascriptconfirm.getText()); // Get text on alert box
    javascriptconfirm.accept();

    myTestDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'confirm']")).click();
    javascriptconfirm = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();

    javascriptconfirm.dismiss();
    javascriptconfirm = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();
    System.out.println(javascriptconfirm.getText()); // Get text on alert box
    javascriptconfirm.accept();

}
}
```

Hope it helps you:)

Comment: all I see is `switchTo().alert().accept()` in your example...what about handling `window.confirm()` or `window.prompt()`?

Answer (score 8):

```
protected void handleAlert() {
    try {
        getDriver().switchTo().alert().accept();
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
        // That's fine.
    }
}
```

Comment: It is going into catch block. I am sure confirm box will come but still i is not able to identify that. Is alert is different than confirm here? Do I need some other code?