# clicking confirm box of browser using selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, phantomjs, ghostdriver

My program fails when it encounters a confirm box. I need to click that confirm box in order to proceed. I could not dig into its Html(using firebug) or so. Some one please let me know how to handle this situation??
Even this didn't work

```
enter code here
DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
capabilities.setCapability(
PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
            "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
WebDriver myTestDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
myTestDriver.manage().window().maximize();
myTestDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'confirm']")).click();
try {
Thread.sleep(2000L);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Alert javascriptconfirm = myTestDriver.switchTo().alert();
javascriptconfirm.accept();
```

[Selenium Web Driver : Handle Confirm Box using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13560120/selenium-web-driver-handle-confirm-box-using-java)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Phantom does not currently handle alert and confirm dialogs out of the box (see [here](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/20#issuecomment-15641983)).

Until Phantom & Ghostdriver implement native support, the workaround is to inject javascript to handle the alert or confirm yourself.

Here's a snippet of C# code to do it, assuming that you want to simulate the user clicking "OK" in the confirm dialog:

```
string script = "window.confirm = function(message) { lastConfirmationMessage = message; return true; }";
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver;
executor.ExecuteScript(script);
```

You can then execute other javascript to retrieve "lastConfirmationMessage" if you want to assert that the text was as expected.